# IBM Watson Conversation Pressure Testing - How Many Simultaneous Dialogs Possible?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

We are working on a chatbot using IBM Watson Conversation Services, in a discussion we came up with a question about how many simultaneous conversations our chatbot is capable of. For example, what happens if 7 billion users chat with our bot at the same time? What is our chatbot's maximum capacity of simultaneous chats? Hope we described the question well.

Comment: Are you using a dedicated IBM Watson Conversation Service for your 7 billion users or hoping to handle 6 million with the (kind of shared resources) of the "public" service?

Answer (score 0):

I believe which ever middleware architecture you are using will have performance issues before you hit large performance issues with the IBM conversation service. The IBM service is already handling millions of connections currently. 
I also believe IBM would love to see this number of connections, along with the billed API calls.